# Join and Left Join not pulling data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm only receiving data from the first table `social_members` and not the two other tables `_meminfo` and `_memtext`. both tables have data in them with the same `m_id` value that is in `_meminfo` and `_memtext`.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT sm.*, DATE_FORMAT(sm.m_lld,'%m/%d/%y') 
                    AS m_lld_formatted 
                    FROM social_members sm
                    JOIN social_meminfo smi ON (sm.m_id = smi.m_id)
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN social_memtext smt ON (sm.m_id = smt.m_id)
                    WHERE sm.m_user = '".mysql_real_escape_string($en['user'])."'"); 

if (@mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) call404();
$line = @mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
        $en['m'.$key] = str_replace("\n",'<br/>',stripslashes($value));
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($line); echo '</pre>';
echo $en['mm_pos']; // test from social_meminfo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your query you explicitly say that you only want data from the social_members table.

```
SELECT sm.* ....
```

has that effect (sm.* = all the columns from the table aliased as sm). if you want all the columns generated by your query, then you should instead do

```
SELECT * ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention social_meminfo and social_memtext columns in your SELECT clause.

try this

```
SELECT * from .....
```